# IPTables drop HTTP traffic based on pattern

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to drop all HTTP traffic (GET/POST) on some TCP ports where specific services are listening. Recently script kids are using Layer 7 DDoS to affect the TCP listening services.

Upon research I found that it's possible to drop traffic based on packets, so I came up with something like:

```
-m string --algo kmp --hex-string '|474554202f20485454502f312e310d0a|' -j DROP
```

`474554202f20485454502f312e310d0a` being 'GET / HTTP/1.1'

However I find this a bit crude and not really effective, since they can just do GET /robots.txt and bypass it.

With that being said, what other method/options are out there to achieve my goal?

Many thanks

Comment: Are you commited to (only) using iptables? You'll not be able to usefully look into TLS connections that way anyway, I don't think. A common way would be to have fail2ban look at your server's logfiles and have it issue IP blocks.

Comment: At the moment yes. The services I am running accept TCP (no SSL or TLS at the moment), hence they abuse it to send HTTP traffic and crash them. Regarding fail2ban, I would use it but I don't have much experience with it. It could also be "too late" to ban these IP's when the attacks are distributed. So in my mind: just drop HTTP-like traffic on port 12345 directly.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Also, what do do you mean by "only iptables", what else is there?

Comment: I meant "only" as in "without other tools that do things like removing blocks after a certain time, can do other things in addition to blocking, etc.", because sometimes, people have a "this is an embedded device, I can't install anything" situation, and sometimes, they've just not heard of useful tools for the job (like fail2ban).

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Ah I understand. Yeah this is not the problem for me, I can and will install and configure almost anything. At the moment I have some perl scripts to help with this situation. Anyway, back to the question at hand... any idea?